# Dimension too large error

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\DeclareMathOperator{\artanh}{artanh}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] % reset theorem numbering for each chapter

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition} % definition numbers are dependent on theorem numbers
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example} % same for example numbers
\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{killcontents}{}
\let\solution\killcontents
\let\endsolution\endkillcontents

\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{10cm}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem{mytheo}{}%
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newcommand{\question}[1]{\vspace{.1in}\noindent $\fbox{\textbf{#1}}$}

\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=2em\indent}}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (8,-.6);
\coordinate (B) at (2,3);
\draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;

\tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](O,A){\textit{b}}
\tkzLabelSegment[left=2pt](O,B){\textit{a}}
\tkzLabelSegment[above right=2pt](A,B){\textit{c}}

\tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.8,opacity=.4](A,O,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.5](A,O,B){\textit{C}}

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= orange,size=1.2,%
opacity=.4](B,A,O)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](B,A,O){\textit{A}}

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= orange,size=0.8cm,%
opacity=.4](O,B,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.5](O,B,A){\textit{B}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I'm receiving a 'Dimension too large' error from this code. From answers to similar questions, I understand that I need to change some of the values I have used. Can anyone suggest which values I should change, and by how much?

Comment: Make a complete example, including the preamble. This makes it much easier to test your code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have done this now.

Comment: @A. Goodier Use `\tkzMarkAngle[fill= orange,size=1.2cm,opacity=.4](B,A,O)` . You forget `cm` near `1.2`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.